# How to use Airbrake's pybrake Django integration?

Tags: python, django, logging, airbrake

I'm trying to apply the Django integration steps described for [`pybrake`](https://github.com/airbrake/pybrake), a Python exception notifier for Airbrake. The Django project contains several apps, one of which is called `lucy_web`. In my setttings, I've defined the `AIRBRAKE` setting like so:

```
AIRBRAKE = dict(
    project_id=os.getenv('AIRBRAKE_API_KEY'),
    project_key=os.getenv('AIRBRAKE_PROJECT_ID'),
    environment=os.getenv('AIRBRAKE_ENVIRONMENT', default='production'),
    root_directory=os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()))
```

The `LOGGING` setting is:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_true': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': os.environ.get('LOG_LEVEL', 'ERROR'),
            'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
        'airbrake': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'pybrake.LoggingHandler',
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.db.backends': {
            'level': os.environ.get('LOG_LEVEL', 'ERROR'),
            'handlers': ['console'],
        },
        'lucy_web': {
            'handlers': ['airbrake'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I've replaced the key `'app'` in the README by `'lucy_web'`, the name of one of the apps in the project.

Now, as I understand from Python's logging documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html), any `Logger` object with a name like `'lucy_web.foo.bar'` should propagate to the `'lucy_web'` logger and get handled by its handler, which is defined above to be the `pybrake.LoggingHandler`.

To test this, I tried the following test in `lucy_web/tests/test_airbrake.py`:

```
import os
import logging
import pybrake
from django.test import SimpleTestCase

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class AirbrakeTest(SimpleTestCase):
    def test_1(self):
        notifier = pybrake.Notifier(
            project_id=os.getenv('AIRBRAKE_PROJECT_ID'),
            project_key=os.getenv('AIRBRAKE_PROJECT_KEY'),
            environment='production',
            root_directory=os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()))

        try:
            raise ValueError("Hello")
        except Exception as err:
            notifier.notify(err)

    def test_2(self):
        logger.error("Foobar")
```

The first test is a more 'verbose' approach in which a `pybrake.Notifier` is instantiated directly. This succeeds in sending an error to Airbrake, as seen from our Airbrake dashboard:

[image]

However, the second test, which relies on the logging integration, doesn't appear to send any notification to Airbrake. Is this not supposed to be how it is supposed to work?